# MATLAB loop through an array of vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector, iteration

I can't figure out the appropriate syntax to do this. I have 4 vectors that each have 15 elements. I want to extract a vector of length 4 containing the first element of each of my original vectors, and then do things with it. Then I want to do the same things with the second element of each vector, etc. and store all the answers in a matrix or array. Something like this:

```
for i = 1:15
    new_vec=zeros(4);
    n=1;
        for fc = {vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D}
            new_vec(n)=fc(i);
            n=n+1;
        end
     Final_answers{i}=functionDoThings(new_vec);
end
```

But I get:

```
> The following error occurred converting from cell to double: Error
> using double Conversion to double from cell is not possible. Error in
> my_script (line 31)
>             new_vec(n)=fc(i);
```

I feel like there is a simpler way to do this that I am missing.

Comment: Put the 4 vectors together into a 4x15 matrix (which is probably what they should have been in the first place) and then take each 4x1 column of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is looping over a 1x4 cell:

```
for fc = {vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D}
    new_vec(n)=fc{1}(i)
    n=n+1;
end
```

This results in fc being a 1x1 cell in each iteration.

To access the actual data inside the cell you would need to use curly brackets:

```
for fc = {vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D}
    new_vec(n)=fc{1}(i)
    n=n+1;
end
```

{1} will access the first cell of fc and (i) the desired element.

However it is easier and faster to use a matrix like beaker suggested:

```
fc = [vec_A; vec_B; vec_C; vec_D];
for i = 1:15
    new_vec = fc(:,i);

    ...
end
```

Comment: You should probably pull `fc` out of the loop. There's no need to generate the same array 15 times.

Comment: valid point! I was just unraveling the inner loop, without thinking about any further improvements.

Comment: Thanks this was just exactly what I needed.
Your fc gave me a 64x1 matrix though, so I ended up with:
    fc = [vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D];
    for i = 1:15
     new_vec = fc(i,:);
     ...
    end

Comment: `fc = [vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D];
    for i = 1:15
     new_vec = fc(i,:);
     ...
    end`

Comment: ah yeah, it depends whether your vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D are 1x15 or 15x1 Arrays.
In my example they would be 1x15.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that `fc(i)` is returning a `cell` while it tries to put it in the array as a `double`. Obviously, you can't convert an array to a single element.

So, instead of storing it into an array it should be stored into a cell.

```
for i = 1:15
    new_cell=cell(4);
    n=1;
    for fc = {vec_A, vec_B, vec_C, vec_D}
        new_cell{n}=fc(i);
        n=n+1;
    end
 Final_answers{i}=functionDoThings(new_cell);
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That would help but functionDoThings needs an array of doubles. Thanks though!